# Why is my systemd script not working, while reboot pi my app not receiving signal(SIGTERM, SIGINT )

Tags: pi-3, systemd, reboot

```
[Unit]
Description=+++++++++++App start/stop+++++++++++++++++
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
StandardOutput=null
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/app_start > /dev/null
Restart=always
RestartSec=120
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/app_start_stop
KillMode=control-group
TimeoutStopSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can anyone suggest why my systemd script is not working?

Comment: After Running sudo systemctl daemon-reexec all running services received signal while reboot but if i reboot without this command systemctl daemon-reexec not able to receive SIGINTorSIGTERM signal in process.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you bother with receiving signals? *systemd* will do all this for you with `systemctl start app_start` and `systemctl stop app_start`. I don't know what your script do and why do you need to do special things with `ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/app_start_stop` to stop the service `app_start` but there are some things that should be noted when `app_start` fails. `app_start_stop` will not execute then <sup>**(1)**</sup>. `User` and `Group` is default root, also `KillMode=control-group` so you can omit this. Because *network.target* is a static unit it is important you use `Wants=` for it. You also suppress any output. I would not do that because you cannot see any (error) messages. By default they will go into the journal. You can look at it with

```
pi ~$ journalctl --unit app_start.service
```

Without knowing what your script do I would set up the unit as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=+++++++++++App start/stop+++++++++++++++++
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/app_start
Restart=always
RestartSec=120
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/app_start_stop
TimeoutStopSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With all the timing conditions it is difficult to see what happens with the service `app_start` particularly when it fails or it is killed with `TimeoutStopSec` and then the `app_start_stop` isn't executed but the service starts again after 120 seconds. I would try to make a more stable script.

**references:**
[1] man systemd.service

Answer (score 1):

Your `ExecStart` command line has [invalid syntax](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.